# How to get linked account with current user in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to link my firebase account to my google account and facebook account, and till here everything is working fine.here is my code how I am linking accounts.

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });
```

**Now I want to get, is my current account is linked to facebook or google. is it possible to get this information or should I save this information to the database?**

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users
You can take this reference and it shows how to get the users and how to manage them properly

Comment: @AbhishekSharma thankyou so much for you rply , i want to know whether current user account is connected to fb, google and other social media account or not .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to get, is my current account is linked to facebook or google?

You can check the provider id to see if the user is signed in with Google or Facebook like this:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    for (UserInfo userInfo : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
        if (userInfo.getProviderId().equals("google.com")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User is signed in with Google");
        } else if(userInfo.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User is signed in with Facebook");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the following code:

```
List<? extends UserInfo> infos = user.getProviderData();
for (UserInfo ui : infos) {
    if (ui.getProviderId().equals(GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
        Log.d(TAG, ui.getProviderId());
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much, i did almost same and got reference from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getProviderData()

Comment: is there a way to check which social accounts are connected to the current logged account?

Comment: @Sergio I think you should ask a separate question for that.