# How to start new activity after get email verified (firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to start new activity only once the email has been verified but i have AuthStateListener setted for google and facebook login as well.

How can i separate google/facebook login and email login startActivity?

I tried to include .isEmailVerified in the current AuthStateListener but is not working.

This is what i've setted for google and facebook login that is working fine:

```
mAuthStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
        FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(mFirebaseUser != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Accesso effettuato corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Effettua l'accesso per continuare", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
```

I tried this:

```
mAuthStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
        FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(mFirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Accesso effettuato corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Effettua l'accesso per continuare", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
```

Im sure it's quite easy to solve it but i'm learning so be patience please.

Comment: String provider = user.getProviders().get(0); did you tried this. this will provide the last login provider.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362602/how-to-get-linked-account-with-current-user-in-firebase/52365854) out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just adding && mFirebaseAuth.isEmailVerified, it looks working fine

```
mAuthStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
 if(mFirebaseUser != null && mFirebaseAuth.isEmailVeried){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Accesso effettuato corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Effettua l'accesso per continuare", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};
```