# Does Firebase Authentication password reset email still send an email for providers other than Email/Password?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using sendPasswordResetEmail for a password reset.

```
suspendCoroutine<Result<Boolean>> { cont ->
                firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        cont.resume(Result.Success(true))
                    } else {
                        val exception = task.exception ?: Exception("Email not sent")
                        cont.resume(Result.Error(exception))
                    }
                }
            }
```

If the sign-in method provider is a provider different from Email/Password, (e.g: Facebook), does firebase automatically return an unsuccessful task, or does it still send a password reset email?

My understanding is if the user signed in previously with a different provider, then sending a password reset to that email address is purposeless, right?

Screen that contains logic for resetting password:

[image]

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're asking if you're currently signed in with Facebook, what happens if you try to send a password reset request?

Comment: so if you already signed in with Facebook previously, and now that email is registered in the Firebase Auth console under "Facebook" provider, then you want to send a password reset to that email address. Does firebase returns an unsuccessful task since reseting that password won't have any affect to its actual password because it's a Facebook password and not a Firebase password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're [sending a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) to a user, you're only allowing the user to reset the password in their Firebase Authentication account. This operation has nothing to do with the password that already exists in the social provider account that was associated with that Firebase account.

IMHO, this option should only be used in the case of a user that creates an account with email and password. So if you don't want to allow the reset of a password for social media accounts, then don't enable that feature in your app, for any social accounts. That's it.

Comment: Yes, in my app I have Firebase email/password + Facebook login. My question developed from the case where a user mistakenly wants to reset his/her password because they forgot it even though they previously logged with Facebook. In this case, it will be confusing if they still receive a reset password email. IMO, an unsuccessful task response when trying to reset a non firebase account makes sense. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the best you can do is not to provide a sending password reset email option to the user that uses auth with a provider. An exception cannot be thrown because when a user signs in with a provider such as Facebook, it also signs in with Firebase. So an account that was created with Facebook is also a Firebase account too.

Comment: Not yet. "the best you can do is not to provide a sending password reset email option to the user that uses auth with a provider." <- Using this logic means that: 1) I know that the email is a non email/password provider before triggering the password reset. 
2) I should create two textfields (one for firebase email/password providers and FB providers)? 
I added a screenshot of the UI to the question btw. Sorry if I'm confusing you.

Comment: I want to know if: 1) I have to stop sendPasswordResetEmail from triggering if I figured that the providers is a non Firebase email/password OR 2) Firebase recognizes that the provider is a non email/password provider, and it will do the job of returning a unsuccessful task response? Thank you

Comment: 1) There is no concept of non-Firebase accounts. It doesn't matter if you created an account with email and password, or Facebook, you'll always end up having a Firebase account. If you want to check what is the exact provider, then you [should check that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362602/how-to-get-linked-account-with-current-user-in-firebase/52365854). 2) After you find out that the type of the account, you can perform any logic you want, even not providing the option for sending a reset password email. It's up to you to decide what to do.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but there is a confusing part. If I'm checking what's the provider ID of a user, that means that user is already signed in? (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null). <- From my understanding, this logic will return null if the user has not signed it yet, right? So how can I get the provider ID if the user isn't signed it yet?

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, you should use [FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(String email)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)).